# Defaultdict and constant_factory vs lambda

Tags: python, defaultdict

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) for `defaultdict` (from collections) provides an example:

> A faster and more flexible way to create constant functions is to use `itertools.repeat()` which can supply any constant value (not just zero):

```
def constant_factory(value):
    return itertools.repeat(value).next
d = defaultdict(constant_factory('<missing>'))
d.update(name='John', action='ran')

'%(name)s %(action)s to %(object)s' % d
>>>'John ran to <missing>'
```

So that seems to work, but so does this:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: '<missing>')
d.update(name='John', action='ran')

'%(name)s %(action)s to %(object)s' % d
>>>'John ran to <missing>'
```

This last version seems more compact and cleaner to me.  Is there a clear speed or memory or maintainability (or any other) reason to define `constant_factory` rather than using a `lambda` function?  I'm using this in some code that will be used (and maintained) by others, so I want to make sure I'm not just playing to my own preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.repeat(value).next` is much faster than a lambda function. This is because a lambda function executes python bytecode, while `itertools` primitives are implemented in C.